# Are King Uzziah & King Azariah the same person?

Tags: referent-identification, isaiah

Is King Uzziah in Isaiah 6:1, the same as King Azariah in 2 Kings 15:1-7?

> **Isaiah 6:1** In the year that King **Uzziah** died, I saw the Lord, high and exalted, seated on a throne; and the train of his robe filled the temple.

> **2 Kings 15:1** In the twenty-seventh year of Jeroboam king of Israel, **Azariah**[a] son of Amaziah king of Judah began to reign. **2** He was sixteen years old when he became king, and he reigned in Jerusalem fifty-two years. His mother’s name was Jekoliah; she was from Jerusalem. **3** He did what was right in the eyes of the Lord, just as his father Amaziah had done. **4** The high places, however, were not removed; the people continued to offer sacrifices and burn incense there. **5** The Lord afflicted the king with leprosy[b] until the day he died, and he lived in a separate house.[c] Jotham the king’s son had charge of the palace and governed the people of the land. **6** As for the other events of Azariah’s reign, and all he did, are they not written in the book of the annals of the kings of Judah? **7** Azariah rested with his ancestors and was buried near them in the City of David. And Jotham his son succeeded him as king.

Comment: What text are you quoting from, please ?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX - please take the tour below.  I cannot find any reference to Azariah in Isaiah.  He is the same person as Uzziah which is his name in Isaiah.  Compare 2 Kings 15:1 with 2 Chron 26:1.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I was referring to 2 Kings 15:1 and Isaiah 6:1.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes both are the same person.
2. Uzziah means “My strength is the Lord”
3. Azariah means “the Lord helps.”
4. Refer to the below verses and you will see that while the names of the king are different the rest of the details match

> **2 Kings 15:1** In the twenty-seventh year of Jeroboam king of Israel, ***Azariah[a]*** ***son of Amaziah*** ***king of Judah*** began to reign. **2** He was ***sixteen years old*** when he became king, and he reigned in Jerusalem ***fifty-two years***. His ***mother’s name was Jekoliah****; she was from Jerusalem. **3** He did what was right in the eyes of the Lord, just as his father Amaziah had done. **4** The high places, however, were not removed; the people continued to offer sacrifices and burn incense there.

> **2 Chronicles 26:1** Then all the people of Judah took ***Uzziah***,[a] who was ***sixteen years old***, and made him king in place of his ***father Amaziah.*** **2** He was the one who rebuilt Elath and restored it to Judah after Amaziah rested with his ancestors. **3** Uzziah was ***sixteen years old*** when he became king, and he reigned in Jerusalem fifty-two years. His ***mother’s name was Jekoliah***; she was from Jerusalem. *4* He did what was right in the eyes of the Lord, just as his father Amaziah had done. **5** He sought God during the days of Zechariah, who instructed him in the fear[b] of God. As long as he sought the Lord, God gave him success.